Failed to publish to the AWS S3 bucket from the Codemagic workflow editor
I have configured the workflow for Flutter web to build the web app and publish it to the AWS S3 bucket. I’ve provided admin access to the AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key, but I’m still getting an error while publishing the web app to S3.
I was able to manually push the web app using the AWS CLI with the same AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key, but the error persists when publishing through the workflow.
These are the error logs I am receiving from Codemagic.
== Gathering artifacts ==
== Publishing artifacts ==
Publishing artifact web-web.zip
Publishing to AWS S3 Bucket 
Uploading files to AWS S3 Bucket  failed.
Make sure that the provided AWS Access key ID and secret access key are valid, the bucket  exists, and that the specified access credentials can be used to upload files to this bucket.
Failed to publish to AWS S3 Bucket 
Skip publishing to Firebase App Distribution: no matching artefacts found.
Build failed 
Publishing failed 
Failed to publish to AWS S3 Bucket 
Any help with resolving this issue would be appreciated.
